# NullPointerException within OnClick() on db fetch

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter

Working on figuring out my NullPointerException within my custom simplecursoradapter when trying to refresh the data in my view. When using SimpleCursorAdapter you cannot use NotifyDataSetChanged() so I need to create a new adapter and I am having difficulty passing on the data required.

```
public class DxSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
Context context;
Activity activity;
DxDbAdapter dbh;
DxSimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;

protected String subcategory;

public DxSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, String param) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context=context;
    this.activity=(Activity) context;
    subcategory = param;
}

public DxSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.context=context;
    this.activity=(Activity) context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_detail, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.fav);
    holder.diagnosis = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.diagnosis);
    holder.code = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.code);
    row.setTag(holder);
    return row;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView diagnosis;
    TextView code;      
}

class Status {
    int status;
    Long id;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context con, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    int favstatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DxDbAdapter.FAV));
    Status state = new Status();

    if (favstatus == 1) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_on_normal);
        state.status = 1;
    }
    else if (favstatus == 0) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_off_normal);
        state.status = 0;
    }

    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DxDbAdapter.DIAG_ID));
    state.id = id;
    holder.image.setTag(state);
    holder.diagnosis.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DxDbAdapter.DIAG)));
    holder.code.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DxDbAdapter.DIAG_CODE)));

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Status current_state = (Status) v.getTag();

            ImageView fav = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fav);

            if (current_state.status == 1) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"Update fav status to 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            else if (current_state.status == 0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"Update fav status to 0",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

                    dbh = new DxDbAdapter(context);
            dbh.open();
            Cursor newCursor = dbh.fetch(1, subcategory);
            String[] columns = new String[] {"diagnosis", "diagcode"};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.diagnosis, R.id.code};
            adapter = new DxSimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.list_detail, newCursor, columns, to);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    String diag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DxDbAdapter.DIAG));
    String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DxDbAdapter.DIAG_CODE));
    holder.diagnosis.setText(diag);
    holder.code.setText(code);
}
```

The issue is with **subcategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("SUBCATEGORY");** and **Cursor newCursor = dbh.fetch(1, subcategory);** and that I have to reference the Activity that is using the adapter. I guess I am having issues on the correct syntax to reference the Activity so that I don't get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really pass in the subcategory from your parent activity since this value will not change while using your adapter (instead of retrieving it every single time you bind to a row)

Ex: from the parent activity you would do something like

```
String subcategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("SUBCATEGORY"); 
DxSimpleCursorAdapter adapter = DxSimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to, subcategory);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then obviously you would need to modify the constructor of your adapter so it took that string and then assigned it to your subcategory variable within the adapter

Comment: I have added a constructor which has the additional field and the ListActivity which calls the DxSimpleCursorAdapter now passes on the subcategory value but I still have an issue with NullPointerException occurring on **Cursor newCursor = dbh.fetch(1, subcategory);**. The method fetch() has worked in other activities so I am not sure what the issue is with my limited knowledge of Java.

Comment: dbh looks to be null. I don't see anywhere in your code where you are assigning or creating your DxDbAdapter dbh object

Comment: I have added dbh = new DxDbAdapter(context); dbh.open(); to my code above and now my NullPointerException has gone down to lv.setAdapter(adapter);. Any ideas? Am I assigning and creating dbh object correctly?

Comment: that should be fine. Why do you have a listview variable inside of your adapter? Your listview should exist in your main activity. Not in the adapter. think of it this way: activity holds the listview -> the listview holds the adapter -> the adapter holds the items to display

Comment: to fix that I removed the ListView variable and just have it as `setAdapter(adapter)` but it tells me setAdapter(DxSimpleCursorAdapter) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener. Do I need to create a method for setAdapter?

Comment: replace the setAdapter(adapter) call with DxSimpleCursorAdapter.this.setAdapter(adapter) instead.

Comment: still says the setAdapter method is undefined... with DxSimpleCursorAdapter.this I can setViews, setCursor, etc but no setAdapter method.

Comment: Oops sorry. Try using DxSimpleCursorAdapter.this.changeCursor(newCursor);  You don't need to create a new adapter

Comment: thanks for your help. My bookmarking of favourites works for the most part except for some other issues with close() not explicitly being called on database. Hopefully, I can work through it.